# Alphabetic gesture recognition in all screens of my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, touch, gesture

I am working on detecting alphabetic gestures in my app. So when the user draws a C in the screen there is a special action that takes place and so on. I am using recognizer class that has pre defined data about each alphabets touch points and the detection is ok.  I want this feature in all my screens so i add the below methods to appDelegate class and detect touches in the window only, what happens here is that other views like tableview ,scrollview inside screens block the touch events from being sent to the window - If that happens perfectly then my code would work like a charm. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)processGestureData
   {
     NSString *gestureName = [recognizer findBestMatchCenter:&center angle:&angle   score:&score];
     NSLog(@"gesture Name: %@",gestureName);

     if ([gestureName isEqualToString:@"N"] || [gestureName isEqualToString:@"n"])
     {//handle N gesture
     }

     if ([gestureName isEqualToString:@"C"]) 
     {//handle C gesture
     }

   }


 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
  [recognizer resetTouches];
  [recognizer addTouches:touches fromView:self.window];
 }
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
  [recognizer addTouches:touches fromView:self.window];
 }
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
  [recognizer addTouches:touches fromView:self.window];

  [self processGestureData];
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you detect which alphabet is drawn by user ? Any idea ? I dont know how to and where to start ?

Comment: I used https://github.com/preble/GLGestureRecognizer to perform gesture recognition, you have to take sample points for your gesture and add it a JSON file with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some touch intercepting window that will sit about all touches. 
If your gesture is recognised, process that, else pass on touch to your view controller. Refer [this link](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-trick-for-capturing-all-touch-input-for-the-duration-of-a-touch/) for details

Comment: Yes I did that, but then my underlying views do not receive the touch events at all.

Comment: I did the same kinda thing given in your link.